# Check Array in MFC C++

Tags: c++, arrays, mfc

This code that I have is not working as it should.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 140; i++)
    {
        if (OneLine_Array.GetAt(i) == "Pass" || "Fail" || "Warn" || "Active")
        {
            OneLine_State.Add(OneLine_Array.GetAt(i));
        }
    }
```

It will work though if i have it as

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 140; i++)
    {
        if ((OneLine_Array.GetAt(i) == "Pass") || (OneLine_Array.GetAt(i) == "Fail") || (OneLine_Array.GetAt(i) == "Warn") || (OneLine_Array.GetAt(i) == "Active"))
        {
            OneLine_State.Add(OneLine_Array.GetAt(i));
        }
    }
```

I was wondering is there a shorter way of doing this rather than replicating the same line of code over and over again?

thanks.

Comment: What type is OneLine_Array?
Also, you first bit of code shows a misunderstanding of the or (||) operator. It combines boolean expressions. The boolean expressions in your code would be:

1) OneLine_Array.GetAt(i) == "Pass"

2) "Fail"

3) "Warn"

4) "Active"

Comment: jr-be is right: it basically evaluates the first condition, then it tries to evaluate `if("Fail")` and `if("Warn")` etc. Since `"Fail"` is a string not a boolean value that's why your results aren't what you are expecting.

Comment: All the arrays specified would be CStringArray. Ahhhhh, thanks user! that explains the bit of code that I have wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store the result of `GetAt` before you get to the condition, then you don't need to evaluate it multiple times:

```
auto x = OneLine_Array.GetAt(i);
if (x == "Pass" || x == "Fail" || x == "Warn" || x == "Active")
```

For a sufficiently short variable name (but please call it something nicer than `x`), this will be shorter than your second example.

The reason your original condition doesn't work is because each of `"Fail"`, `"Warn"`, and `"Active"` are `true`, so the logical OR will also be `true`. They are `true` because they are of array type which can be converted to a pointer to their first elements (`char*`). A non-null pointer is converted to `true`.

Comment: Thanks rabbit! Didnt thought of that way to do it. Yeah, Ive called it CurrWord haha. thanks everyone for the explanations and answers! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this ( OneLine_Array.GetAt(i) == "Pass" || "Fail" || "Warn" || "Active")     ==> this is not possible in C++

it will be better to save the string of the OneLine_Array.GetAt(i) in variable and make the "=="

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention MFC C++. With a better performance, I'd suggest using CMap (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s897094z.aspx) to store your strings. It does speed up the comparision.

Answer (score 0):

Although I prefer what @sftrabbit answered, you could write a little helper for this.

```
template<typename A, typename B>
bool equals_one_of(const A& a, const B& b)
{
    return a == b;
}

template<typename A, typename B, typename... Args>
bool equals_one_of(const A& a, const B& b, const Args&... args)
{
    return equals_one_of(a, b) || equals_one_of(a, args...);
}



int f()
{
    if (equals_one_of(OneLine_Array.GetAt(i), "Pass", "Fail", "Warn", "Active"))
    {
        // ....
    }
}
```